# Dependencies issue with Ngb bootstrap in Angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I m new to Angular and I'm trying to create a image slider carousel in angular using ng bootstrap's component but after I have created an angular project I have installed "ng bootstrap" (in project) using `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` and have imported it in app.module.ts using `import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';`.

I have also installed `ng add @angular/localize` in the project but i m not sure what is wrong it is showing me the error below:

```
ERROR in The target entry-point "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" has missing dependencies:
 - tslib
 - @angular/core
 - @angular/common
 - @angular/forms
 - rxjs
 - rxjs/operators
```

I'm following https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started. What should I try next?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest installing jQuery and Popper.js in addition to Bootstrap:

```
npm install bootstrap --save
npm install jquery --save
npm install popper.js --save
```

in your project folder go to src/styles.cs and add the following line of code

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

then go to src/angular.json and add the following lines to "scripts":

```
 "scripts": [
 "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
 "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js", 
 "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

Hope this help.

Comment: After adding this the app loads but the screen is blank, nothing displayed

Comment: after following the previous steps you don't have to add "ngbModule" from bootstrap, you can directly use bootstrap classes in all of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in root folder of your project then run this command

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

or

```
npm i --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```